# PHP Error deleting file

Tags: php, file-permissions, permission-denied, unlink

Error deleting file if there are multiple connections to multiple page.
Error:`Warning: unlink(folder/1.txt.txt) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\htdocs\fopen.php on line 7`

`Note:` If only one connection to access everything normally occurs (no error occurs).

PHP code `fopen.php`:

```
<?php
function fastWrite($a){
    echo 'Coping file: "',$a,'" to "',$a,'.txt"<br>';
    copy($a,$a.'.txt');

    echo 'Delete file: "',$a,'.txt"<br>';
    unlink($a.'.txt');
}

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    fastWrite('folder/1.txt');
    echo '<hr>';
}
?>
```

html/javascript code (to simulate multiple connections):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>my test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myTest(z){
    $.ajax("fopen.php?time="+(new Date().getTime()),{"success":function(data){
        $("<div></div>").addClass("sty").html(data).appendTo("body");
    },"error":function(a,b,c){
        $("<div></div>").addClass("sty").html([a,b,c]).appendTo("body");
    }});
}
</script>
<style>
.sty{
border:1px #000 solid;
overflow:auto;
margin:5px 0 0 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="teste.html">New test</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dd = "";
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    dd += "myTest(\"#a"+(i+1)+"\");\n";
}
eval(dd);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

---

**Solution:** [clearstatcache](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)

Comment: make sure, the file is not being used by other processes

Comment: This is obviously race conditions. What the problem?

Comment: There is, why would not fail when there is only one connection. When there's just no connection errors occurs. Help me please.

Comment: @nikita2206 Test the code if you can, the following error occurs: `Warning: unlink(folder/1.txt.txt) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\htdocs\fopen.php on line 7` . This error does not occur when there is only one connection

Comment: please, be clear. what are you doing with file and why do you want to delete? describe the situation more explicitly. what connections do you mean?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `1.txt.txt`?  Is this intentional
?

Comment: @Cthulhu This is an example. Please test the code.

Comment: Ok, here's what's happening there:

#1 request opened

#1 copy() called

#2 request opened

#1 copy() ends copying file

#2 copy() called

#1 unlink() called

Unlink fails with error because file is locked by another proccess that doing copy.

Comment: @nikita2206 I did not understand, you tested my code? thanks. edited:Now came the rest of your answer

Comment: @nikita2206 Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: What are the permissions of the files that get created?

Comment: Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: @slashingweapon That makes a difference on windows? Like I said the error only occurs with multiple connections, only one connection to access the code works normally, please test the code to see the problem.

Comment: @slashingweapon The error occurs on all operating systems I've tested. Windows Xp, Seven and Debian Linux.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't think that you should use files, databases are usually solve race conditions problem.

Comment: @nikita2206 this is just a caching system database. This structure must not fail. To have a guaranteed cache. I need to work with this idea

Comment: Use flock() and files with different names.

Comment: @nikita2206 I can not use different names because as I said this is just a simulation. I'll try to flock ().

Comment: @nikita2206 I thought best at what you said about different names, I made the copy(); using a random name that never repeats and ready solved.

Put your answer there for me please mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having a problem because two processes are trying to copy and delete the same file at the same time.  Because they are separate processes, you can't easily control the order in which they do things.

Imagine two processes, running `fastWrite()` at the same time:

- t1 copies 'a' to 'a.txt'
- t2 copies 'a' to 'a.txt'
- t2 deletes 'a.txt'
- t1 tries to delete 'a.txt', but fails because it does not exist

This is called a "race condition".

If you don't mind that the `unlink` call will sometimes fail, you can ignore the error by  using the '@' symbol in front of the command:

```
@unlink("$a.txt");
```

I'm pretty sure that saving user-generated data into the same file over and over again isn't your ultimate goal. You obviously encountered this problem in the pursuit of something larger.  Maybe you should start a new question more focused on **that** problem.

If you just need a temporary file to work with during the connection, don't always name the file the same.  Instead, you could:

```
function doStuffToFile($fname) {
    $tempName = $fname . "." . getmypid() . "." . rand();
    copy($fname, $tempName);
    // do stuff to your temporary file
    unlink($tempName);
}
```

Comment: Nah, it wouldn't be "perm denied" then. It's happening when one copies and another tries to delete.

Comment: Instead of @, would not verify that the process is open? I tried is_readable and is_writable but still the same error occurring.

Comment: between `is_writable()` and `unlink()`, another process can still delete the file.  @nikita2206 may have a point about permissions.  What OS are you using, and what are the permissions of the files you are creating?

Comment: After copying the file, you should try `chmod("$a.txt", 0777);`  and see if you at least get a different error.  Your race condition will still exist, but you might get a "file not found" error instead of a permission error.

Comment: @slashingweapon tried using CHMODE. The error continues to occur. Like I said the error only occurs with multiple connections/requests to code.

Comment: One possible solution is to use [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to create a lock file when you're using the file. `flock` is supposed to _wait_ on locks.

Comment: @Salman_A `$fname . "." . getmypid() . "." . rand();` solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two or more scripts that write to and delete *1.txt.txt*. This is called a race condition. *Script1.php* has no direct way of knowing if *Script2.php* is using a file, you need to implement this mechanism yourself.

A simple solution is to create a lock file before using the shared file and delete the lock file once you are done with it.

There is a new problem then: how do you ensure that the two scripts do not create the lock file at once? *Script1.php* might find that lock file isn't there but before it actually creates the file, the processor switches to *Script2.php* which also finds the lock file missing. What then?

PHP provides a useful [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) function. I am not aware of the gory details but I believe it should solve your problem, to some extent, on some platforms at least.

```
<?php
function fastWrite($a)
{
    # //// LOCK \\\\
    $fp = fopen("fastwrite.lock", "w");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX) === false) { # PHP will stop at this line until the lock is acquired
        die("flock failed");
    }
    # \\\\ LOCK ////

    echo 'Coping file: "', $a, '" to "', $a, '.txt"<br>';
    copy($a, $a . '.txt');

    echo 'Delete file: "', $a, '.txt"<br>';
    unlink($a . '.txt');

    # //// UNLOCK \\\\
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_UN) === false) {
        die("flock failed");
    }
    fclose($fp);
    # \\\\ UNLOCK ////

}
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    fastWrite('1.txt');
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

PS: I was not able to reproduce the race condition on my system.

Comment: Is there a way to acquire a lock on the whole directory and prevent other processes from deleting it, but let them read all the files in the directory?